# How to alter style of statement block line in algorithm environment of algorithm2e package?

Tags: rules, algorithm2e

I'd like to change the style of the line that runs along the side of a statement block in a pseudocode algorithm typeset using the `algorithm` environment of the `algorithm2e` package. Here's the initial example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{A simple algorithm.}
    \Begin
    {
      \ForEach{item}
      {
        \ForEach{sub-item}
        {
          do something.\\
        }
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: initial line style]

But I'd like to add little endcaps on the lines and adjust the spacing a bit. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

[image: desired style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the `vlined` package option draws the vertical and horizontal rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\algocf@Vline}{\vrule}{\vrule\hspace{-0.25em}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{A simple algorithm.}
  \Begin
  {
    \ForEach{item}
    {
      \ForEach{sub-item}
      {
        do something.\\
      }
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The idea behind this solution is to draw the vertical rule, and then back up half the width of the regular horizontal rule (default width is `0.5em`), before setting the rest of the code blocks.

One can adjust the width of the little horizontal rule as well, if need be.

This should suffice for most uses.